# Function restriction of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V, \Omega$ open subsets of $\mathbb{R^d}$, with $V \subset \Omega$. The function  restriction $R:\mathcal{D}'(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}'(V)$ given by $u \mapsto u|_{V}$ is continuous. If we consider $S:\mathcal{E}'(\Omega)\cap \{u \in \mathcal{E}'(\Omega): \hbox{ supp } u \subset V \} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}'(V)$, given by $Su=u|_V$. Is the function $S$ injective?

Comment: Is $\Omega$ a subset of $V$???????

Comment: $V \subset \Omega$

Comment: @mathworker21, why so many question marks?

Comment: I want to make an identification of a function $u \in \mathcal{E}'(\Omega)$ such that $\hbox{ supp } u \subset V$ with a function $u \in \mathcal{E}'(V)$. I'm using John Horvath's book of topological vector spaces.

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{E}'(\Omega)$ is the space of compactly supported distributions.

Comment: If $T \in \mathcal{E}'(\Omega)$ and $\phi \in C^\infty_c, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi(x)dx = 1, \phi_n(x) = n^d \phi(nx)$ then $T_n = T \ast \phi_n\in C^\infty_c$ and $T_n \to T$ so it is easy to see how you can restrict the support or anything else (Fourier transform, differentiate, integrate).

Comment: I need of a continuous linear and injective map from $\mathcal{E}'(V)\cap \{u \in \mathcal{E}'(\Omega):\hbox{ supp  } \subset V\}$ into $\mathcal{E}'(V)$.  For this reason I thought of this restriction $R$.

Comment: For $V$ open then $\mathcal{E}'(V) = \{ T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d), \text{supp}(T) \subset V\}$

Comment: Thank you! One more question. If I consider $S:\mathcal{E}'(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathcal{E}'(V)$. Is this function injective?

Comment: How do you define $S$ in term of what I said ?